# Installing tools with dotnet core app using csproj files instead of project.json

Tags: .net-core

I'm attempting to install Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools in a new dotnet core app with Visual Studio 2017 RC. Is there a tools section for the csproj file?

I also attempted to install it via the nuget package manager, but I get the following error:

> 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'REDACTED'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS2017 RC 2, you need this:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
```

If you are using VS2017 RC1, you need this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild1-final" />
```

You must set them manually, as NuGet wants you to use the preview version.